# Can't push_back() after 1000th element in a vector in c++11

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(){
    vector <long long> vec(2000,1);
    vec.reserve(2000);
    int count = 0;
    vec.push_back(31);
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
        count ++;
    }
    cout << count << " " << vec.max_size() << " " << vec.at(1543) << " " << vec.at(1000);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code I can't get 1000th element which is 31. I get 1 instead of it. I can use push_back() for elements which index is less than 1000.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You created 2000-element vector whose all elements are `1` and then added `31` at the end of that. Therefore, only the 2001st element (or 2000th element using 0-origin) of the vector is `31` and the 1000th element is `1`. There are no "1000th element which is 31" in your code.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. What do you mean you "can't"?

Comment: _"1000th element which is 31"_ No it isn't. Why do you think that?

Comment: You probably meant to write `vec.resize(2000);` instead of `vec.reserve(2000);`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah, but `vec.resize(1000);` will invalidate `vec.at(1543)`...

Comment: Yeah, it'll throw a `std::this_question_makes_zero_sense` exception.

Comment: It's very odd to count to `vec.size()` with a loop. Do you think that the loop is any different from just writing `count = vec.size();`, or was it simplified from some other code that did something meaningful with the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1000th element is actually just `1` due to this constructor.

```
vector <long long> vec(2000,1);  // fill with 2000 elements, each set to 1
```

Then after this line

```
vec.push_back(31);  // element [2000] is now 31
```

Therefore your final vector is

```
{1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 31}     // length 2001 elements
```